# Substitute of org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument() method in solr v6+?

Tags: apache-spark, solr

Since method **org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument()** is removed in solr 6, what is the subtitute available now to convert SolrDocument to SolrInputDocument? Why this change is been done?

**EDIT-1:** After @MatsLindh answer(Doesn't work):

```
1 List<SolrDocument> sds = MyUtil.getMySolrDocs();
2 for(SolrDocument sd : sds){
3        SolrDocumentBase sdb =  sd;
4        SolrInputDocument sid = (SolrInputDocument)sdb;
5        System.out.println("Docs id : "+sid.get("id"));
6        System.out.println("Docs title : "+sid.get("title"));
7        
8 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is demonstrated by the source code of [`ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/5.2.1/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.java#ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument%28org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument%29) in Solrj 5.2.1:

```
public static SolrInputDocument toSolrInputDocument(SolrDocument d) {
  SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

  for (String name : d.getFieldNames()) {
    doc.addField(name, d.getFieldValue(name));
  }

  return doc;
}
```

Comment: Which means we need to loop through all the fields in a SolrDocument and for every document. Actually, I was looking for a better way of doing this. Thanks for answer.

Comment: This will only take care of the 'stored' fields in solr. I recommend using the original source to re-index the document if you have fields which are not stored.

Answer (score 2):

As shown above, you can create SolrInputDocument from SolrDocument by copying fields; don't forget to copy children documents too (used by block join queries), example:

```
    public static SolrInputDocument toSolrInputDocument(SolrDocument solrDocument) {
        SolrInputDocument solrInputDocument = new SolrInputDocument();

        for (String name : solrDocument.getFieldNames()) {
            solrInputDocument.addField(name, solrDocument.getFieldValue(name));
        }

        //Don't forget children documents
        if(solrDocument.getChildDocuments() != null) {
            for(SolrDocument childDocument : solrDocument.getChildDocuments()) {
                //You can add paranoic check against infinite loop childDocument == solrDocument
                solrInputDocument.addChildDocument(toSolrInputDocument(childDocument));
            }
        }
        return solrInputDocument; 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In 6.x they both share the same abstract parent class, `SolrDocumentBase`, so to convert between them you should be able to use a cast between the classes through the parent if necessary.

The [reason for the change](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8339) was that they both contain almost the same, identical functionality, so instead of having two classes that do almost the same and shares nothing, the functionality was moved to a parent class that keeps the common methods and properties and let the implementing subclasses do the specific work for those use cases.

Comment: Hi Mats, thanks for your answer. I tried to cast the objects but getting ' java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument cannot be cast to org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument' error at line no. 4, Please see my EDIT-1 for code. Is it possible to cast between two subclasses? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Good point - downcasting probably wont work. But SolrDocumentBase implements `Map<String,SolrInputField>` and SolrInputDocument has `SolrInputDocument(Map<String,SolrInputField> fields)` as a constructor. Have you tried `new SolrInputDocument(sd);`?

Comment: Ok, I tried this by replacing line 4 to "SolrInputDocument sid = new SolrInputDocument(sdb); " , now line 5 giving me error - "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputField", even I tried 'sid.getFieldValue("id")' which didn't worked either. While trying 'sid.get(new SolrInputField("id"))' I got all the ids as NULL. I guess the conversion of sd to sid is not happening properly. What you think?